# How can I add another value in ModelView and pass it from my Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In my Products PartiallView table

```
@model IEnumerable<Products.Models.ProductModelView>
```

I'am trying (hide) not showing some buttons if user departmentId is not the same as product departmentId

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Product type</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
            </td>

            //  I want to hide if current inlogged userDepartmentId is not the same as product departmentId
            // Like @if(@item.ProductDeptId == userDepartmentId) {
            <td>
                <Button class="btn btn-success glyphicon btn-xs glyphicon-plus" onclick="return EditDelete(@(item.ProductId) )">Edit/Delete</Button>&nbsp;
            </td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
```

Here is my Class, ViewModel and Action that I'am trying to create but don't know how to pass to my PartielView

```
 public class Product
 {
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     public string productName { get; set; }
     public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
 }

public class ProductModelView
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public int UserDepartmentId { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Lager()
{
    using (context)
    {
        string user = User.Identity.Name;
        int deptId = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == user).Select(d => d.DepartmentId).SingleOrDefault();

        // Here I don't know how to continue ... I try like this
        Product pr = new Product();
        ProductModelView prModel = new ProductModelView();
        prModel.ProductId = pr.ProductId;
        prModel.productName  = pr.productName ;
        prModel.DepartmentId= pr.DepartmentId;
        prModel.UserDepartmentId = DeptId;

        // And then, how to return and what to return?

        return PartialView("_ProductList",  prModel); // Is this right? Returning prModel?
    }
```

Can anyone please help me to formulate my Class, ViewModel and my Action?

Comment: your view is expecting `IEnumerable<Products.Models.Product>` and you're passing an object of type `ProductModelView`?

Comment: @adiga thank you for response. No I just typed wrong. I mean IEnumerable<Products.Models.ProductModelView> but stil I don't how pass those value

Comment: Create a "Composite" object and pass it instead.

Comment: You're still passing one object of type `ProductModelView`. But your view is expecting a collection of `ProductModelView`s. So in your controller, you must create a List of `ProductModelView` and pass that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a "composite" object and pass it instead (as per @Uwe):

```
public class ProductListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductModelView> Products { get; set; }
}
```

and change `@model` accordingly:

```
@model ProductListViewModel
```

*Or* construct and pass `IEnumerable<ProductModelView> products` to `return PertialView()`:

```
// IQueryable<Product>
var products = from p in context.Products
               where p.DepartmentId == depId // aware! would cause 2 queries to db, shall be rewritten
               select p;
var prModels = from p in products.AsEnumerable() // 'memorize' db query into in-memory objects
               select new ProductViewModel
               {
                   ProductId = p.ProductId,
                   ProductName = p.productName,
                   DepartmentId = p.DepartmentId;
                   UserDepartmentId = deptId;
               };
return return PartialView("_ProductList", prModels);
```

---

How to rewrite:

Either configure a navigation property (*recommended*):

```
public class Product
{
    public User { get; set; }
}
```

*Or* perform a direct join:

```
var products = from p in context.Products
               join u in context.User on p.UserDepartmentId = u.UserDepartmentId // or whatever it is
               where u.UserName == userName // it's better to use userId which is likely the primary key
               select p;
```

Comment: Greate..  Thank you very much!